# Get-AzureVMImage but from MY IMAGES

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to find Azure ImageName from my custom image stored in MY IMAGES. Is it possible to do it with PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-AzureVMImage | where { $_.Label -match '<<your-image-label>>'}
```

or

```
Get-AzureVMImage | where { $_.ImageName -match '<<your-image-name>>'}
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, but I already tried this cmdlet and it cannot see my image. Actually it cannot see any image from MY IMAGES.

Comment: I am trying the same thing, I am using ARM. I am NOT able to use my own template as well.